# Insert Url last 2 characters in database php

Tags: php, url, path, insert

I am trying to insert last 2 chararcters of Url into my database.When i insert everytime it takes some number like "2147483647".How to insert the correct last 2 chararcters of Url.
    '$array = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

for($i = 0, $l = sizeof($array); $i < $l; $i++){
    $obj = $array[$i];

```
if($obj->{'leaf'} == true){
    $leaf = 1;
} else{
    $leaf = 0;
}

if($obj->{'parentId'} == null){
    $parentID = 'null'; 
} else{
    $parentID = $obj->{'parentId'};
}

if($obj->{'Duration'}==''){
    $duration = 0;
} else{
    $duration = $obj->{'Duration'};
}




$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

$gantt_id = substr(strrchr($url, '='), 1);
/*if($obj->{'gantt_id'}==null){
    $gantt_id = 0;
} else{
    $gantt_id = $obj->{'gantt_id'};
}
*/
$q = 'INSERT INTO j_gantt_tasks SET Name = "'.$obj->{'Name'}.'", StartDate = "'.$obj->{'StartDate'}.'", EndDate = "'.$obj->{'EndDate'}.'",
      Duration = "'.$obj->{'Duration'}.'", DurationUnit = "'.$obj->{'DurationUnit'}.'", PercentDone = "'.$obj->{'PercentDone'}.'", Cls = "'.$obj->{'Cls'}.'", gantt_id="'.$gantt_id.'",
      parentId = "'.$obj->{'parentId'}.'"';

$r = mysql_query($q);
if(!$r){
    echo db_error($q);
}

$obj->{'id'} = mysql_insert_id();
```

} 
echo json_encode($array);'

Answer (score 0):

give a try to [substring](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

```
$url = (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ?
     "https://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] : 
     "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];


$last2 = substring($url,-2);
```